# Proving the max of a quadratic form ${\mathbf x}^T\mathbf A \mathbf x$ can be attained when $x$ is from $n$-dimensional hypercube

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms

**updated**: Maybe my original question is somewhat misleading. I rewrite some of the post.

This is some research problem I'm working on.

---

I have an $n\times n$ symmetric [positive-definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) matrix $\mathbf A$. I also have a set of $2^n$ vectors $\mathbf x_1,\cdots,\mathbf x_{2^n}$ from an $n$-dimensional [hypercube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube) $\gamma_n$ of $\{1, -1\}^n$.

<del>I already know the maximum of the [quadratic form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticForm.html) of the matrix $\mathbf A$ and vectors $\mathbf x\in\{1, -1\}^n$ is a known constant $c$:</del>

Using some kind of [AM-GM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) like inequality, I know that the quadratic form is at most $c$

$$
\mathbf x^T \mathbf A \mathbf x \leq c
\quad\text{subject to $\mathbf x \in \{1,-1\}^n$} 
$$

In this case, I want to show that

1. there exists a vector $\mathbf x\in\{1,-1\}^n$ that achieves $\mathbf x^T \mathbf A \mathbf x = c$, and
2. if that's possible, I'd like to show that this maximizer can be computed [efficiently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency).

---

Some related problem is the '0-1 Positive-Definite Maximum Problem' from [Girtzmann and Klee](http://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/4992/1/522.pdf):

- *Instance*: a symmetric positive definite matrix $\mathbf B$ and an integer $\lambda$
- *Question*: Does there exist a vector $\mathbf x\in\{0,1\}^n$ such that $\mathbf x^T \mathbf B \mathbf x \geq \lambda$?

They showed that this problem is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).

---

I think my problem is different from '0-1 Positive-Definite Maximum Problem' because I already know the upper bound of the quadratic form and ask whether this upper bound can be achieved from a vector from a hypercube.

**My Question**: Is there any trick for an existential proof that such a maximizer exists in my setting?

One trick I can come up on top of my head right now is the [Averaging Argument](http://www.tricki.org/article/Averaging_arguments), but this seems too strong: I'm afraid the averaging argument works only when all the $2^n$ quadratic form values amount to the desired maximum $c$.

Comment: I think I'm missing something : You are evaluating a function on a finite subset aren't you ? Then you necessarily have a maximum that is reached. What am I missing in your problem ?

Comment: @BertrandR It is an algorythmic question. The thing is that the size of the set is exponential ($2^n$) and he wants the computer to find the answer in polynomial time. Or something like this:)$$\ $$
Federico: $c$ is maximum over $\{-1,1\}^n$, right? So you don't ask if the max can be achieved (you assume that), but you ask about the vector realizing the maximum, right?

Comment: Ok, so in fact when the OP says "I want to show that there exists a vector x∈{1,−1}n that maximizes the above equation and moreover to show that this maximize can be computed efficiently" the problem is about efficiency and not existence. I see

Comment: @BertrandR R I'm rewriting the post. Sorry for any confusion.